# Graficar dos arreglos

Tags: java, array, eclipse, gráficas

Pregunta tonta: ¿Es posible graficar dos arreglos de enteros? Del tipo int [] x, tamaño n. Estaba pensando hacer una gráfica lineal son el índice de Collatz (mi código funciona a nivel consola y sí arroja los resultados esperados).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Collatz {

```
static int collatz(int n){
  int aux;
  
  if(n%2 ==0)
      aux = n/2;
  else
      aux = 3*n + 1;
  
  return aux;  
}

public static void main (String[]args){
 
    System.out.println("Prueba del índice de Collatz\n");
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("¿Hasta qué número deseas calcular? (Debes ingresar un número entero positivo).\n");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    
       if(n<0)
       do {
           System.err.println("Número inválido. Ingresa un número entero positivo.\n");
            n = sc.nextInt();
       }while(n<0);
          
    
    int m,i,aux=0;
    
    System.out.println();
    
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)  //Va de 1 al número que elegimos
    {      
        System.out.println("n = " + i);  //i y n son variables inamovibles; empleamos un auxiliar para aplicarle todas las operaciones con el índice de Collatz
        aux = i;             
        m = 0;   //Este contador debe iniciarse en 0 cada vez que se evalúe una nueva i
        
        if(i!=1)
            System.out.print("Desarrollo = " + i + " -> ");
       
        while(aux != 1)
       {
          m++;   
          aux = collatz(aux);
          
          if(aux != 1)
              System.out.print(aux + " -> ");
          else
              System.out.println(aux);
       } //Fin de while
          
    System.out.println("#C = " + m);
    System.out.println();
     
   }  //Fin de for
}  //Fin de main
```

}  //Fin de clase

---

Mi idea es que las variables i y m, en cada iteración del for, sean almacenadas en arreglos y así poder graficar al final. ¿Alguna sugerencia? De antemano gracias :3

Comment: Hola MIguel, se me ocurre que podría declarar dos **List** y guardar los valores en ellos, ya que hacerlo con arrays, deberías saber previamente la cantidad de números a almacenar.

Comment: Una pregunta, no deberías almacenar **m** y **aux**?.

Comment: Efectivamente. Luego se me ocurrió crear dos ArrayList, almacenando cada valor de i y de m. Imprimiéndolas al final sí obtengo cada valor generado. Lo que no sé es cómo graficar ja.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo algo muy básico, tal vez para que te sirva de inspiración.

```
    for( i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {    
         System.out.println( "n = " + i ); 
         aux = i;
         m = 0;   
         if( i != 1 ) {
      //      System.out.print( "Desarrollo = " + i + " -> " );
         }
         num.add( i );
         String salida = "";
         while( aux != 1 ) {
            m++;
            aux = collatz( aux );
            for( int ii = 0; ii < aux; ii ++ ) {
               salida += "*";
            }
            salida += "\n";
            if( aux != 1 ) {
      //         System.out.print( aux + " -> " );
            }
            else {
      //         System.out.println( aux );
            }
            otr.add( m );
         } 
      //   System.out.println( "#C = " + m );
         System.out.println(salida);
      }
```